# Pandas transform aggregated clolumns with factors to rows

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame like this:

```
a1xbxc,a2xbxc
show    1   2
```

where a,b,c are attributes that can have different values e.g. a1,a2 for a and so on. Now the way I have this df is not good for plotting barcharts. I want to have it in a normal way like this:

```
show    factor a | factor b | value
 a1     |  b      | 1
 a2     | b       | 2
```

How would I go to achieve this? I know I should somehow split each header by ("x") and then find out to which factor it belongs and then write it into a new row, but it seems somewhat that there must me some easy way to do this in pandas.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(df.columns.str.split('x').to_series().apply(tuple))

df.stack([0, 1])

           c
show a1 b  1
     a2 b  2
```